# Xamarin.Forms iOS: How to make a PDF thumbnail?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview, pdf.js

My app has a Documents folder with a number of PDF files, which have to be represented in a listview by thumbnails. I use pdf.js to generate a first page image inside a WebView.
This approach works fine for Android, but not on iOS. WkWebView does not load the PDF file. It throws an error inside my pdfPreView() function saying it cannot access the PDF.

This is the Content of the WebView:

```
public class PdfThumbnail : WebView
{
...
    var _thumb = "file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5DE26435-E018-4E31-B9CF-C76A79F2C11C/Documents/db/demo/upload/ba_415_de_gb.pdf";
    var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
    htmlSource.BaseUrl = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;  // for iOS
    htmlSource.Html = $@"
        <html>
          <script src='pdfjs/build/pdf.js'></script>
          <script src='js/PdfPreview.js'></script>
          <body style='background-color:white;'>
            <div style='display:flex; justify-content:center'>
              <canvas id='preview'></canvas>
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>pdfPreView('{_thumb}','preview')</script>
          </body>
        </html>
    ";
```

Here the JS pdfPreView function:

```
function pdfPreView(url, canvasId, width=0, height=0) {
    var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js'

    // Asynchronous download of PDF
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
        console.log('PDF loaded');
        // Fetch the first page
        ...
        }, function (reason) {
        // PDF loading error
        console.error(reason);
    });
}
```

I assume WkWebView does not allow access to a file based URL pointing to the Documents folder. But how to enable this?

Comment: it seems like your question is really "how do I display local content in a WKWebView", not "How to make a PDF thumbnail".  See https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_local_content

Comment: @Jason: That's not the point. The script files are accessible. But pdf.js is going to show a file (the pdf) outside the bundle but inside the document folder, which resides in a different container, isn't it?

Comment: @FrankHintsch Hi, you could have a look at the [file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories) in iOS.

Comment: I know. But Javascript is not allowed to read from the Documents Hierarchy ...